# Why do I need to specify deep: true in Vue watcher inside Pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, pinia, vue-reactivity

This is my sample:

```js
// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

import { useStore } from './store.js'

const store = useStore();
const { foo } = storeToRefs(store)

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('nvmnghia mounted')
  setTimeout(() => foo.value.bar++, 1234)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

```js
// store.js
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useStore = defineStore('store', () => {
  const foo = ref({ bar: 1 })
  watch(foo, foo => console.log({ foo }), { deep: true })
  return { foo }
})
```

If I remove `{ deep: true }`, the watch log isn't printed. Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) said watchers are deep by default (their word: "implicit"):

> When you call watch() directly on a reactive object, it will
> implicitly create a deep watcher - the callback will be triggered on
> all nested mutations: [code example]

Why do I still have to specify it?

Furthermore, if I still don't want to set `deep`, I have to do a React-like modification:

```js
foo.value = { bar: foo.value.bar + 1 }
```

Pinia docs said `storeToRefs()` is enough to get reactive, but it doesn't apply here.

Comment: The question seems to be based on false premise. The link says, "watch is shallow by default"

Comment: @EstusFlask No I can't find that. The only "by default" thing I can find is that it's lazy by default, which is not related to deep option.

Comment: This is the first sentence exactly in the section you linked, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers . On the other hand, there's no word "implicit" on the page

Comment: For me the doc link says, in the first sentence: "it will implicitly create a deep watcher".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Vue docs said watchers are deep by default, but that's for reactive not ref.In Vue Source code,reactive is implemented by Proxy so its deeply reactive, and ref is implemented by getter and getter like vue2 so its not deeply reactive.In addition,when ref is using to an object like your code,In fact it seems like do this: const foo = ref(reactive({ bar: 1 })), so the foo.value is deeply reactive,and you can test it :watch(foo.value, foo => console.log({ foo }))

Comment: Hi, just want to let u know that I'm still learning so I don't accept your answer just yet. Hope I'll be confident enough to do it in a few more weeks!